# Magento get product link using V1 API

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, api, url, products

```
$storeUrl."/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[page_size]=200&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1"
```

It returns products list but I want to get each product link. How it is possible?

Comment: You need to make custom Api for that.. Magento doesn't provide the same

Comment: url_key is stored under custom_attributesin the response

Comment: I got the url_key from response but when I try to use it as domain.com/url_key.html  then it returns 404 not found error.
Can you please send me any reference link ?

Comment: Do you know about productRepo API ?

Comment: if yes then we can guide you to achieve this.